# Refresh jQuery code after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

Let's say, for example, that I have some buttons that calls AJAX requests when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').each( function() {
        $(this).click( function() {
                    alert('Clicked.');
            // ...AJAX request...
        });
    });
});
```

When I click on a button, everything works fine.

But if I load the buttons with an AJAX request and then I click on them, the code above stops working.

How can I get rid of this?

I have tried the `on()` method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').each( function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
                    alert('Clicked.');
            // ...AJAX request...
        });
    });
});
```

But it's just the same. Works normally, doesn't work on AJAX-loaded content.

I'm stuck, please help me.

P.S.: I am using the latest version of jQuery (v1.7.1).

Comment: @Shevelo - that is depricated in favor of .live() also not prefered/depricated over .delegate() or .on() or .bind()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('body').on('click','button', function() {
                    alert('Clicked.');
            // ...AJAX request...
        });
});
```

In this way is the `body` element that handles all the `click` event on the `<button>` elements and it works even if they are added through AJAX.

Instead of using the `<body>` tag you could use something that wraps those `<button>`...in any case read the docs of jQuery for [on()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), it's pretty straightforward.

P.S. in case you are wondering, `live()`works exactly as i used `on()`, jQuery just intercept events when they bubble up the DOM

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the click handlers after the buttons are already on the page.  If you're doing it on page load, then the buttons loaded by ajax aren't there yet to accept the handler assignment.

Comment: Not totally true if you anchor your event management properly.

Answer (score 0):

try `on`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click', function() {
                    alert('Clicked.');
            // ...AJAX request...
    });
});
```

and one loop will be enough , no need of `each` loop because `on` loop itself detect all the `button` elements and trigger on click event.

Comment: Truth, but after 1.7, on() is the preferred method. Before 1.7, .live() and .delegate() are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the safest (and least error-prone) approach is to bind the click-events AFTER you've loaded the buttons with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I have a preference for the delegate in this intance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('body').delegate('button','click',function(){
       alert('Clicked.');
    });
});
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/cKVGb/

some background discussion on delegate,live and bind: http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery

And, finally the .on() documentation so you might use that as well:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

so you were ALMOST right! first already present buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function() { 
      alert('Clicked.');
                     // ...AJAX request...
    });
});
```

now new ones (and old ones)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'button', function() { 
      alert('Clicked.');
                     // ...AJAX request...
    });
});
```

Comment: Truth, but after 1.7, on() is the preferred method. Before 1.7, .live() and .delegate() are the way to go.

Comment: yes, but now you should use on() as delegate() is deprecated in 1.7

Comment: The main, important difference between .on() and .delegate() is really the sequence of the entities, and the ability to .off() - see the .on() documentation for conversion notes from the older methods to .on().